# Can someone explain me what is the difference between an "empty" statement and a normal semicolon in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me what is the difference between a normal **semicolon ;**  that comes after every statement and the **empty statement ;** in **javaScript**

`console.log(1) ;/* semicolon */          console.log(2)`

and the empty statement that sometimes comes as the body of  **if, for, while, do-while** statements in **javaScript**
eg:

```
if (true)
 ; /* empty statement */
```

is there a difference between both a **semicolon ;** and an **empty statement ;**

Answer (score 2):

Each javascript statement should (although not all must) end with a semicolon, 
'empty statement' also. A semicolon in an empty statement is just a semicolon that completes the statement.

For the final explanation: 'empty statement' is an statement without any sign hence its name. It must contain a terminating semicolon or the JS parser would not be able to distinguish it from other whitespace characters. Thus, the semicolon sign; It is not an statement but is a mandatory semicolon ending the empty statement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212517/discussion-on-answer-by-slawomir-dziuba-can-someone-explain-me-what-is-the-diffe).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript semicolons indicates the end of a statement. A semicolon is not necessary after a statement if it is written on its own line, although it is considered good practice to do so. But if more than one statement on a line is desired, then they must be separated by semicolons.

```
//these are ok
console.log(1)
console.log(2);

//this won't run
console.log(1) console.log(2) console.log(3)

//this will run
console.log(1); console.log(2); console.log(3);
```

An empty statement is used to provide no statement in circumstances where the JavaScript syntax would expect one. For example in a for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; array[i++] = 0)
; //JavaScript requires a statement here so do nothing
```

Also some JavaScript statements must be terminated with semicolons and are therefore affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). If you wish to deepen more into this I recommend you check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) on MDN. For a better understanding you may check the [ECMAScript standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar).

Comment: so theres a difference between the two right but in MDN webdocks they have not mentioned about javaScript **semicolons ;** even though they have mentioned about the **empty statement ;**

Comment: @user13104441I updated my answer with more references you can check. As you say MDN doesn't seem to elaborate much about this. However MDN has a lot of information, maybe there is a pretty good article about this that we missed. If you have the time check the ECMAScript standard, it's is in a very technical language but is worth checking it out.

Comment: so this means whenever we write a semicolon after **if, while, for, do-while** statements **it will be parsed as an "empty statement ;" other than just being a "statement terminating semicolon ;"** and whenever we write a  **semicolon ;**  after every statement  **it will be parsed as a "statement terminating semicolon ;" and it will not be parsed as an "empty statement ;"**

Comment: So if its true that the **semicolon** is parsed as the **empty statement** when we write something like: `if (true) /*empty*/; ; else alert(1);` must not give an error because the first semicolon is a statement **an empty statement** and the second semicolon is the **statement terminating semicolon** but why the above code gives an error and another example is `if (true) alert(1); else alert(2);` which works fine but why the first code gives an error if the first semicolon is treated like a statement **an empty statement**

Comment: @user13104441 It's because the empty statement already has a terminating semicolon, so it shouldn't have another one. The example should be `if (true) /*empty*/;  else alert(1);` In your previous comment the second semicolon after `/*empty*/` raises the error.

Comment: but in my above code the **empty statement** acts like a statement so writing a **terminating semicolon** shouldnt give an error but dunno why it gives an error

Comment: @user13104441 the empty statement is a special case, it always acts as a normal statement with a terminating semicolon. Adding another terminating semicolon gives an error because it would be like having 2 terminating semicolons.

Comment: so this means the **empty statement** acts like both a **terminating semicolon** of the body of **if-statement** and a placeholder statement of the body of **if-statement** in this case the **empty statement** does both the jobs right

Comment: @user13104441 You get the error because you are using the simplified if version, without body braces. Such if accepts the first next expression and only this one as its body. There is no problem with executing many empty expressions one after another:  If (true) {;;;;;;;;;;;;} else {;;;;;}

Comment: yes i know this but now i see no different between a **statement terminating semicolon** and an **empty statement**

Comment: Because there is no difference. 'empty statement' is a statement without any character and ends with a semicolon like other statement.
The semicolon is * not * a statement.